# another generalized Lehmer-Euler-conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory

Lehmer-Euler conjecture states, that there a no composite numbers $n$ satisfying

$(n-1) \equiv 0(\varphi(n))$

Are there any results out there for
$a(n-1) \equiv 0(\varphi(n))$, for integer $a$

esp.
$p(n-1) \equiv 0(\varphi(n))$ for prime $p$

Comment: Can you give a reference for the Lehmer-Euler conjecture?

Comment: It only takes two seconds to find a reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_totient_problem

Comment: no other ideas than referencing the conjecture?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any result of this kind. However, I get these sequences (all terms calculated up to $5e6$):

- $a = 2: 4, 6$
- $a = 3: 9, 21, 65, 1729, 3201, 4125441$ ([A193276](http://oeis.org/A193276))
- $a = 4: 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 28, 66, 91, 561, 946, 6601, 8911$
- $a = 5: 25, 33, 217, 385, 12801, 334369, 1439425$
- $a = 6: 4, 6, 9, 14, 18, 21, 45, 65, 105, 1729, 3201, 2704801, 4125441$
- $a = 7: 49, 145, 12673, 238465, 1259713, 2384641$
- $a = 8: 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 20, 24, 28, 30, 52, 66, 70, 91, 190, 276, 286, 451, 561, 742, 946, 2465, 2806, 5662, 6601, 8911, 11476, 30889, 46657, 88561, 449065, 534061$
- $a = 9: 9, 21, 27, 57, 65, 133, 273, 481, 1281, 1729, 1905, 3201, 15841, 25761, 460801, 851201, 1372801, 3482145, 4125441$
- $a = 10: 4, 6, 22, 25, 33, 217, 385, 793, 1065, 12801, 34945, 334369, 1439425$
- $a = 11: 69, 121, 469, 9361, 52417, 66305, 741937, 3358369, 3810241$
- $a = 12: 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 18, 21, 26, 28, 35, 36, 39, 42, 45, 65, 66, 76, 91, 105, 153, 186, 231, 561, 645, 703, 946, 1729, 3201, 4371, 6601, 7107, 8911, 13833, 126673, 334153, 1333333, 1489665, 1683969, 2213121, 2704801, 4125441$
- $a = 13: 169, 4081, 15505, 25201, 170545, 376993$

Based on these experiments, many things can be conjectured.

I'd guess that every sequence is infinite, except for $a = 1, 2$.